# Get-Childitem directory wildcard "Access is denied"

Tags: powershell, directory, permissions, powershell-cmdlet

I have a script where I recursively delete some bunch of files within certain directory. The problem is in specification of that directory.

When I try to specify it explicitly (i.e. to clear only user1 dir) it works fine:

```
$temp = "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\"
Get-ChildItem $temp -Recurse -Force -Verbose -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | remove-item -force -Verbose -recurse -ErrorVariable FailedItems -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

However when I specify it with wildcard (i.e. to affect **all** users on this PC)

```
$temp = "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Temp\*"
Get-ChildItem $temp -Recurse -Force -Verbose -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | remove-item -force -Verbose -recurse -ErrorVariable FailedItems -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

It fails with the error

```
Get-ChildItem : Access is denied
At line:7 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem $localTempDir -Recurse -Force -Verbose -ErrorAction Sil ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

How that could be?
It is definitely not the permissions issue, 'cause it's **the same** dir.
And yes, I run script with an elevated privileges.
Other dirs specified in such format, e.g.

```
C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Caches
C:\Windows\Temp\*
```

are purged like a charm.

Comment: Hi, couldn't this be related to special/hidden/system profile folders? e.g. `Default`

Comment: Maybe. How to diagnose this?

Comment: Enumerate the profiles, rule out the special ones, apply the rest of your logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use something along these lines, if you want to rule out a list of profiles, and process a list of subfolders:

```
$targets = "AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Caches",
           "AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files"

$special = @("Default", "Public")

$profiles = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users" -Directory |
    Where-Object Name -NotIn $special |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

$profiles | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($target in $targets) {
        $path = Join-Path $_ $target
        #delete/empty $path
    }
}
```

NB: syntax is PS3.0+

Comment: Well, it works without errors, however if I remove `Public` from `$special` script affects it as well. But if I remove `Default`, it's garbage is not removed anyway. Why? Does script process only non-hidden (non-system) dirs? Default folder can contain many temp files too, so should be processed.

Comment: I think `-Force` can help here with `gci`

Comment: Correct! Worked exactly as expected.

Comment: However, it is still not clear to me what is wrong with my wildcard form `C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Temp\*`. Why `gci` fails here?